# Query the Parse database for every single value present inside my Collection of different values - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to query the Parse Database for every single value present inside my Collection of different values. 
What I'm Primarily trying to do is query the List of all Parse Users who have already registered with their phone Numbers in their database.

The basic problem I'm faced with is that the query only returns the first matching value and ignores the rest. What I want to do is that, I want it to go through the entire list of collection values provided and I want to get the List of ParseUsers.

However in my case It only returns a single ParseUser.

Here's My sample Code.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereContainedIn("phone", phoneNumberList);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // The query was successful.
                // Remove the previously cached results.
                    ParseUser.unpinAllInBackground(UN, new DeleteCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseException e) {

                            for(int i =0;i<objects.size();i++){
                                ParseUser user = objects.get(i);
                                String UN = user.getUsername(); System.out.println("UniteName:\t" + uniteName + "\n");
                                String time = user.getUpdatedAt().toString();  System.out.println("Time:\t" + time + "\n" );
                                String ss = user.getString("sa"); System.out.println("Status:\t" + status + "\n" );

                            }


                            // Cache the new results.
                            ParseUser.pinAllInBackground(UN, objects);
                        }
                    });


                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            else {
                // Something went wrong.
                showNegativeAlertDialog("Something went wrong. Please Check Your Internet Connection and swipe down to refresh");
            }
        }
    });
```

Here the phoneNumberList is a Collection of Strings. Also the collection contains other matching values in the database.I'm literally stuck. Anyone, please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want a list of all users having a phone number present you could simply change `query.whereContainedIn("phone", phoneNumberList);` to `query.whereExists("phone");`

Comment: @cYrixmorten this would return a whole bunch of ParseUsers. I only want it to return the bunch of ParseUsers whom I know(Present in my contacts or phoneNumberList)

Comment: Ok that was not clear to me from your question. Then I honestly do not know why it does not behave the way you expect. Perhaps because it requires exact matches of the phonenumbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think xYrixmorten's answer in the comment answers your question:

if you want a list of all users having a phone number present you could simply change

```
query.whereContainedIn("phone", phoneNumberList);
```

to

```
query.whereExists("phone");
```

However, I'm wondering why you want to do that on your client side (android)?  The parse queries will limit you to 100 objects by default, unless you specific a higher limit.  Even then the max is 1000 I believe, which starts being difficult if you really want to iterate through all the users.

I would suggest taking a look at [CloudCode](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/windows).  In cloud code, you could easily iterate through all the users like this:

```
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.each(function(user){ 
      //access all users here
  })
```

Obviously this really depends on what you are trying to do with the users...

Comment: First, thank you for taking time to consider my question.@mogile_oil and @cYrixmorten. But the problem with query.whereExists("phone") is that it would return all the ParseUsers with a phone Number. Whereas what I want to do is only retrieve the ParseUsers with the phone number whom are already present in my contact List. Any idea's on how to do it?

Comment: However I've never tried the Parse Cloud Code. Will  check it out. Hope it helps. Any other quick-fix suggestion is also a welcome

Comment: Thanks guys !! i jus figured it out!! didnt populate the List well!! Thanks for help .. @mogile_oli